# Combine observables into array of observables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have this code in Angular

```
  this.provider.getUids()
      .then(uidObservable => this.uidsSubscription$ = uidObservable.subscribe((uids: string[]) => {
        console.log('res', uids); // array of uids 
        const uidsSet = new Set(uids);  // deletes duplicates 
        uidsSet.forEach(uid => {
          this.userObservables.push(this.otherProvider.getSharedUserData(uid)); // this is the code I need to change 
        });

      }))
```

When I trigger the observale to emit a new value.  **this.userObservables.push** will have duplicate values.

#### Example

Suppose I have only one uid: **AAAAA**
then **this.userObservables** contains only observable to **AAAAA**
Now, When I trigger the observable to emit a new value **BBBBB**
**this.userObservables** will contain observables to   **AAAAA**  **AAAAA**  **BBBBB**

#### Question

Is there a way to prevent this sort of behavior I want to have an array of observables that emit like  **AAAAA**  **BBBBB**

Comment: userObservables is a list wich receives new data on each iteration.
Change this.userObservables.push to equals

Comment: userObservables is an array of observables!

Comment: I was trying to point to this
this.userObservables = [this._ShareListProvider.getSharedUserData(uid))];
Seems you did so by self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
this.uidsSubscription$ = Observable.fromPromise(this.provider.getUids())
  .flatMap(obs$ => obs$)
  .map(uids => new Set(uids))
  .map(uids => uids.map(uid => this.otherProvider.getSharedUserData(uid)))
  .subscribe(observables => this.userObservables = observables);
```

However, `provider.getUids` returning a `Promise<Observable<>>` sounds really weird and should probably be redesigned.

Also note that it's unusual to suffix a subscription with `$`. The typical convention is to suffix observables that way, not subscriptions.

And, lastly, it *also* strikes me as odd that this observable only assigns an array of observables to some array. You'd typically want to continue the chain here so you subscribe to them in whatever fashion you need. Overall, the design of this code looks strange, but without more information this is just a XY problem.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your helping instructions. I had to change .map(uids => new Set(uids)) to map(uids => Array.from(new Set(uids)))

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution although not the best in my point of view. I reset the array of observables at the beginning of the subscribe method.

```
 this.provider.getUids()
      .then(uidObservable => this.uidsSubscription$ = uidObservable.subscribe((uids: string[]) => {
        console.log('res', uids); // array of uids 
        const uidsSet = new Set(uids);  // deletes duplicates 
        this.userObservables = [];
        uidsSet.forEach(uid => {
          this.userObservables.push(this._ShareListProvider.getSharedUserData(uid)); // this is the code I need to change 
        });
      }))
```